# GitHub - Can I add mailgroup to access my repository

Tags: git, github

I have a mailgroup contains list of users. Now, I want to grant the permission for this mailgroup in order to let each user can access my repository. Is this possible? If so, how should I do?
Regards,
Tuyen

Comment: What do you mean by a mail group? There's no mailing functionality in-built into GitHub. Are you talking about teams or collaborators? Or are you talking about a group you've defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your repository is public, you have nothing to do for read (clone/pull) access.

For write access, public or not, you will need for those users to:

- ave GitHub account (not just mails)
- [register them as collaborator](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)

Having just a list of mail addresses would not be enough.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I did.